# Unable to execute a sh file from a Gradle Exec task

Tags: gradle

I configured this simple Gradle task in a project

```
task startMyProgram(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "myProgram.sh", "${System.getProperty("argument")}"
}
```

This sh file is executable (`chmod a+x myProgram.sh`) and is located in the root folder of the project, from where I run the Gradle command.

When I run the task with `./gradlew startMyProgram -Dargument=foo` it fails with the following error message:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "myProgram.sh" (in directory "/Users/paristote/Work/my-project"): error=2, No such file or directory`

I've tried running commands like `commandLine "echo", "Hello World"` and they work just fine.

Does anybody have a clue why this simple command fails?
I'm using Gradle 4.1 if it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to configure the task like this:

`commandLine "./myProgram.sh", "${System.getProperty("argument")}"`

Note the `./` in the executable name.